# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [LoginClass] associated with context path [/Struts2Application]. - [unknown location]

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, action-mapping

Why i am getting this error in my First struts2 application

Home.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="LoginClass" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>User Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="Uname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :</td><td><input type="text" name="Pwd"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
   <struts>
   <package name="Default" extends="Struts_default">
   <action name="LoginClass" class="com.struts2.LoginCheckingClass" method="execute">
   <result name="success">/LoginSuccessPage.jsp</result>
   <result name="Notsuccess">/Home.jsp</result>   
   </action>   
   </package>   
   </struts>
```

LoginCheckingClass.java :

```
   package com.struts2;

public class LoginCheckingClass {


    private String name;

       public String execute() throws Exception {
          return "success";
       }

       public String getName() {
          return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }

}
```

Web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">
  <display-name>Struts2Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

This problem raised for me in earlier date so i fixed by this [Struts2:There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [hello] associated with context path [/struts2App1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664864/struts2there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace-and-action-name-hello-asso) but now could not fix this.

Someone tell me where i am doing mistake?

Comment: `Struts_default` should be spelled as `struts-default`

Comment: @RomanC thank u but this also not fix it

Comment: It's not true, this fixes the package name but you might have a lot of bugs.

Comment: @RomanC yes i am doing mistake in mapping url but i could not fine it..

Comment: It seems like off-topic, because you can't ask a sane question.

Comment: Also `==` is not the way you compare Strings in Java, and returning "success" and "Notsuccess" is doubly inconsistent: one result starts with lowercase, the other with uppercase, then the second word is not capitalized... what is that, randomCase ?

Answer (score 1):

Define your `<package>` configuration as

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
   <action name="LoginClass" class="com.struts2.LoginCheckingClass" method="execute">
     <result name="success">/LoginSuccessPage.jsp</result>
     <result name="Notsuccess">/Home.jsp</result>   
   </action>   
</package>
```

You need to <s>provide the `namespace` attribute</s>, correct the `struts-default` package name and then rename the configuration file to `struts.xml` i.e. all in lowercase.

Comment: You mean page running url or mapping url?

Comment: Yes, address bar url?

Comment: Where is struts.xml located?

Comment: Dont compare with that question bec i lost that project so i rebuilt new one

Comment: Here is WEb-INF -> Classes -> Struts.xml

Comment: Rename the file as struts.xml i.e. all in lowercase.

Comment: Either you add slashes to the location or remove them, you're cool like bindweed.

Comment: At least I'm not trying put people down.. and since it's not a sane question, one must be on bindweed to still hang around.

Comment: I'm not putting people down, but their stupid questions and answers. The purpose of SO to keep smart, clean, and helpful.

Comment: For example you said *need to provide the namespace attribute*, but it's not actually needed. Can you elaborate this.

Comment: Maybe you're blessed with all the smarts but us mortal souls forget things once in a while considering the expanse of technologies under our repertoire. *If you think something's incorrect, downvote..* leave a response (people who genuinely like to share do) but don't go on calling people a bindweed. You just come across as a .. that way.

Comment: Since, the error was complaining about the namespace, I thought it could be the problem along with the case issues I found. But since you've specifically pointed it out to me, it must not be correct. So, I've picked up my Struts reference again, I'll fix the answer and I'll get this guy up and running again. But, I won't call someone a bindweed!

Comment: I tried everything what u said on the answer but nothing helps me.. can you fix this through teamviewer???

Comment: @AndreaLigios yes i tried all solution but nothing helps me so only ask you to fix via teamveiwer.

Comment: I got fix this by simply rename Classes into classes, that WEB-INF -> classes -> struts.xml instead of WEB-INF -> Classes -> struts.xml.

Comment: Case is important. This is not Visual Basic 4. Also apply this discovery to your packages, actions, variables, results, methods, etc... to prevent this from happening again

Comment: TeamViewer.. Ha ha.. that made me chuckle :) Along with the case do not forget Andrea's comment on how not to compare Strings with `==`. That's of very important consequence.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Why chuckle..!  few guys fixed my error through TeamViewer also. what is there to make u chuckle?

Comment: That obviously depends on how much time one has.. I chuckled because I don't know of anyone who provides hands-on support for free.

Comment: yes via Teamviewer can solve complex error.So it's appreciable to fix the error through TeamViewer.